# Notification service is running (always)

Tags: android, notifications, pusher

I hired a developer to build an app for me, I noticed this issue and he said he doesn't think (or know how) it could be fixed. The issue is that every time my app is launched and you're logged in, this notification appears and stays there even if you close the app, you cannot swipe to remove it, you can either remove the app or kill it, or reboot the phone. Any idea how to fix it, he's using "Pusher"

Here's the example after launching the app

[image: Here's the example after launching the app]

Comment: Can you post the notification builder usage in codes of your project?

Comment: please post your java code

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage your service so that it can be started and stooped as per your usage. 
Please post the code or connect with me @ napsterkr@gmail.com for further help.